# Android Wifi Direct WifiDirectServiceDiscovery on API level 15?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I need to compile the WifiDirectServiceDiscovery sample of android 4.2.2 (API 17) on 4.0.3 (API 15), is it possible? if yes, what is the best/fast way to do it?

Comment: I am trying to copy the WifiP2pManager of API17 (with updates) to use explicitly in API15 without using the WifiP2pManager of the android API15 library.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible?

No, because it requires APIs that were only introduced in API Level 16, such as `removeServiceRequest()`.

Comment: I can add missing classes too. But I wonder if there are some hardware requirements rather than software ones. I have Galaxy Tab2 10'1. I think it has all the hardware requirements.

Comment: @ashoker: "I can add missing classes too" -- not unless you are building your own copy of Android from scratch and installing it as a ROM mod on the device.